# Prevent require(...) from looking up modules in the parent directory

Tags: node.js, node-modules

The root directory of my Node project is in a directory that itself is a root of another Node project. So both folders contain `package.json` and `node_modules`. The problem is that in the inner project, sometimes I `require` modules not installed in this project. But Node just silently finds them in the parent project's `node_modules` which leads to annoying surprises. Can I somehow prevent it from doing so? I'd like not to change the directory structure of the projects unless it's the only solution.

Comment: Require won't traverse up the path tree. Can you post your file structure?

Comment: See https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders

Comment: That's not your folder structure.

Comment: @BrandonSmith It will traverse up but only if it doesn't find the module in the current directory

Comment: Better question: why did you write code that requires modules that you don't say it needs in the package.json, so that they install properly?

Comment: Because to err is human?

Comment: I've created a feature-request for [node#43368](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/43368)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Node tries to resolve current module path name and concatenates `node_modules` to each of it's parent directory. [[Source]](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/module.js#L186-L205).

You can override this method at the top of your project module and add some logic to exclude the parent directories from the result path array.

```
//app.js <-- parent project module, should be added at the top

var Module = require('module').Module;
var nodeModulePaths= Module._nodeModulePaths; //backup the original method

Module._nodeModulePaths = function(from) {
    var paths = nodeModulePaths.call(this, from); // call the original method

    //add your logic here to exclude parent dirs, I did a simple match with current dir
    paths = paths.filter(function(path){
        return path.match(__dirname)
    })
    return paths;
};
```

inspired by [this module](https://github.com/patrick-steele-idem/app-module-path-node)

Comment: Now, in 4 quarter of 2018 is it still the only way to disable folders walking in Nodejs? I need it in my TypeScript monorepo....

Comment: @Marecky: you can at least alter the behavior for typescript type lookup, by adding the following to you tsconfig.json: "typeRoots" : ["./node_modules/@types"]

Comment: Is there something similar for ES6 imports?

Comment: @LudovicPollet Is there a way to add this property to a nested tsconfig.json file? I would want this to apply just to a subfolder.